# Making a menu with toggle which can be animated using the top property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a toggle button, so when you click once on `#mbtn`, it must be set to `top:0px` and when you click a second time, it must be set to `top:-110px`.

Here is the code I'm using but it seems like it's not working, where am I wrong?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mbtn').toggle(
        function() {
            $('.menu').animate({
              top: "0px"
            }, 500);
        },
        function() {
            $('.menu').animate({
                top: "-110px"
            }, 500);
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add the basics of the HTML/CSS you are using or a JSfiddle etc?

Comment: @lee_gladding well, my code is not working how can i add basic html to jsfidle when apperantly im trying to make my menu move from invisible (-110px top) to 0pxtop (to visible)

Answer (score 2):

Per jQuery API, you have to use `toggle` with an action, such as `click`. For example:

```
$( "#mbtn" ).click(function() { 
  $( ".menu" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34qo3haq/)

I assume you were trying to hide the menu bar? if so, take a look at `.slideToggle()` instead. Here is the [JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dqjsts0a/).

Comment: no, im trying to do the oposite, the starting point of menu must be hidden, then when u click it must be open, then when u click for second time it must hide it again

Comment: @Tahi , so like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dqjsts0a/1/ Updated the JSfiddle of Melissa